# Randomize drawing of canvas sections

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite

New to javascript (and programming in general) and I am trying to have different characters spawn in my web-game I am making which is represented as different sections in my sprite.

I was wondering how I could achieve this?

I tried to at least change the coordinates as the score would go higher but i couldn't crack it.

```
function Enemy(nX, nY) {
    this.srcX = nX;   //i was trying to sub 
    this.srcY = nY;     
    this.width = 172;
    this.height = 68;
    this.speed = 2; 
    this.drawX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + gameWidth; 
    this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360); 
    this.rewardPoints = 5; 
}
```

This is the other half

```
    Enemy.prototype.draw = function () { 
        this.drawX -= this.speed; 
 ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
        this.checkEscaped();
    };
```

You can see the full thing here. http://dev.yeahnah.tv/gina2/ (fair warning: it's pretty bad.)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**How to efficiently spawn random sprites from a spritesheet**

Store the position and dimensions  of each sprite on a spritesheet in an object:

```
{x:50, y:15, width:170, height:200}
```

Then push all sprite definition objects into an array

```
// store x/y/width/height of each sprite in an object
// add each object to the sprites array
var sprites=[]
sprites.push({x:50,y:15,width:170,height:200});
sprites.push({x:265,y:10,width:140,height:200});
sprites.push({x:460,y:10,width:180,height:200});
sprites.push({x:10,y:385,width:180,height:180});
sprites.push({x:225,y:395,width:200,height:200});
sprites.push({x:445,y:305,width:200,height:160});
```

Then when you want a random sprite, just use Math.random to pull one out of the sprites array:

```
function spawnRandomSprite(){

    // choose a random sprite and draw it
   var sprite=sprites[parseInt(Math.random()*5)];

    // draw the sprite by using the spritesheet position and dimensions in the object
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
        sprite.x,sprite.y,sprite.width,sprite.height,
        0,0,sprite.width,sprite.height
    );
}
```

You could also store a speed and reward points in the sprite object and use those to drive your animation and your scoring:

```
{ x:50, y:15, width:170, height:200, speed:3, rewardPoints:5 }
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YzUmv/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        // store x/y/width/height of each sprite in an object
        // add each object to the sprites array
        var sprites=[]
        sprites.push({x:50,y:15,width:170,height:200});
        sprites.push({x:265,y:10,width:140,height:200});
        sprites.push({x:460,y:10,width:180,height:200});
        sprites.push({x:10,y:385,width:180,height:180});
        sprites.push({x:225,y:395,width:200,height:200});
        sprites.push({x:445,y:305,width:200,height:160});

        // choose a random sprite and draw it
        function spawnRandomSprite(){
            var sprite=sprites[parseInt(Math.random()*5)];
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
                sprite.x,sprite.y,sprite.width,sprite.height,
                0,0,sprite.width,sprite.height
            );
        }

        ctx.font="18pt Verdana";
        ctx.fillText("Loading spritesheet...",20,20);

        var spritesheet=document.createElement("img");
        spritesheet.onload=function(){
            spawnRandomSprite();
        }
        spritesheet.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/angryBirds.png";


        $("#canvas").click(function(){ spawnRandomSprite(); });


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Click on the canvas for a random sprite</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! currently trying to implement this. forgive my slowness! Ill get back to you.

Comment: still trying to implement this, im on a busy schedule, just checking in, i will get back to you!